# Nullpointerexception when I check for running service in Roboelectric test

Tags: java, android, android-testing

I get a NPE when I run a test on an activity whose onCreate() method checks if a particular service is running. In the setup method of the test, I call:

```
ActivityController<MyActivity> ac = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class).create();
    mActivity = ac.get();
```

In the onCreate() method of the activity, I call isServiceRunning()

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(manager != null) {
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (service.service != null && "MyService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
```

It fails with NPE when it executes this:

```
for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
```

manager is not null, but the NPE is thrown in ActivityManager.getRunningServices(int) in the android library.

What should I do if I need this method to pass? I was using Roboelectric 2.2-20130612.001729-6-jar-with-dependencies.jar but I see the problem now even with the latest version.

I was using android SDK version 19, but I now switched to 18 and I still see the problem.

Any ideas?

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  
at android.app.ActivityManager.getRunningServices(ActivityManager.java:1106)
at com.example.MyActivity.isServiceRunning(MyActivity.java:151)
at com.example.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:43)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
at org.fest.reflect.method.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:112)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:116)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:257)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:111)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:123)
at com.example.test.MyActivityTest.setUp(MyActivityTest.java:44)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:233)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:174)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Post the full exception trace.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your if statement to be more inclusive. From the android documentation on the function: 
**Note: this method is only intended for debugging or implementing service management type user interfaces.**

So I would recommend being very careful with your null checkS (note the plural). The order below is important or you might receive the null pointer in the `if` statement's conditional.

1. make sure manager is not null and then
2. make sure the List<> is not null and then
3. make sure that is not empty. 
   (Big difference between null and empty, ex: we cannot run the .isEmpty() function on a null List).

`if(manager != null && manager.getRunningServices(MAX) != null && !manager.getRunningServices(MAX).isEmpty() != null)`

Side Note: Would be easier to read that *after* check number 1 you save list of services to a variable and just have a **second** `if` statement on that variable and *then* do your `for each` statement inside the second `if` statement.